# Get all active DB connections

Tags: php, yii

How to get all active connection when we use multiple databases?

I have tried:

```
foreach(Yii::app()->getComponents() as $component)
{       
    if ($component instanceof CDbConnection) 
    {
        die(var_dump($component));
    }
}
```

but it's look like database component not in `Yii::app()->getComponents()` result.

My db config:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=yyyy;dbname=db1',
        'emulatePrepare' => false,
        'username' => 'user1',
        'password' => 'pass1',
        'schemaCachingDuration' => YII_DEBUG ? 0 : 86400000, // 1000 days
        'enableParamLogging' => YII_DEBUG,
        'charset' => 'utf8'
),

'db2'=>array(
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx;port=xxxx;dbname=db2',
        'emulatePrepare' => false,
        'username' => 'user2',
        'password' => 'pass2',
        'schemaCachingDuration' => YII_DEBUG ? 0 : 86400000, // 1000 days
        'enableParamLogging' => YII_DEBUG,
        'charset' => 'utf8'
),
```

Comment: @Dagon where to show?

Comment: you can check it with `Yii::app()->db->getactive()` or `if (Yii::app->db->active)`

Comment: but this is strange getComponents() should work.

Comment: It does not work because of Yii lazy loading, `db` or `db2` is not instantiated until you explicitly call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in CActiveRecord instance ($model), you can use `$model->getDbConnection();` or `CActiveRecord::$db` to get current connection database;

Answer (score 0):

In class reference you can read:

> public array getComponents(boolean $loadedOnly=true)

So, if you want to get every connection instead of only the actives:

```
foreach (Yii::app()->getComponents(false) as $component)
{
    if (is_array($component) && $component['class'] == 'CDbConnection') 
    {
        print_r($component);
    }
}
```

Should list all